# Two interlocked circles are isotopic to two circles which is not interlocked in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: general-topology

I'm a college student studying Mathematics.

I've got this problem in my topology class

Two interlocked circles are isotopic to two circles which is not interlocked in  $\mathbb{R}^4$. (Also, those two circles don't intersect each other.)

My professor said anyone can prove it, the person will get an A.

But he didn't give us what 'Isotopic' is and how we can find related sources.

I don't want someone else to solve it for me. I just want to know what books I should read and study to grasp this. I tried to google it, but the only source I can find about 'Isotopy' is Wikipedia. However, the explanation in wiki is too hard to understand.(it's so simple) Can anyone recommend me some books that I can refer and study about the problem above?

Thanks,

Comment: Which part of the definition do you not understand? Intuitively, it means that you can take a pair of interlocked circles, and then move them around to get a pair of circles which are not interlocked. I think understanding basic concepts is the only difficulty involved (the idea itself is very easy).

Comment: @ylh0501: Did your professor specify an actual pair of circles that are "interlocked"? (Given the result you're asked to prove, no pair of circles in $\mathbf{R}^{4}$ can be [linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_%28knot_theory%29) in the sense that two circles in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ can be linked.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It was just the first week of the course yesterday. So.. I don't know what are embedding, homotopy, or something. And I cannot imagine how interlocked circles can be deformed into non-interlocked circles.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang He didn't. He drew circles on a blackboard. I think 'link' looks right. But I don't fully understand because his comments are not clear. He didn't teach us what a topology is yet.